# post times are incorrect on deployment, but not when using app locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

So I ran into this strange issue. I have a feed where you can add posts. One of these posts are event posts where you pick a time for when an event happens. I tested this locally and it seems to work fine. It shows the time I had picked. However, when I deploy the app it suddenly displays the wrong time when I post an event. e.g I posted an event that took place at 3:30PM and when it displays the event time is set at 09:30PM.

I am currently in Mexico City and I assume this is 6 hours difference from the UTC. I just don't understand why it is correct when I test it locally and incorrect when the app is deployed. Can someone help me out? I'll post some of my images below to show what the issue is.

(Maybe it can help to mention that I work together on this project with several other people internationally in different timezones)

**this is the post when I try it locally: the content is the time I had intented it to be and as you can see it displays the correct time**

[image]

**the database also seems to save the correct time (see highlighted line)**

[image]

**Here is the app when it's deployed. As you can see I intented to post an event set for 3:30PM, but it ended up showing 9:30PM. So locally it displays correctly, but when deployed not**

[image]

**this is the code that handles adding the post to the database. below you'll see the result of the first console.log in this piece of code**

```
const add = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const postData = req.body;
console.log('req.body', req.body);
        // // Id it's event post, convert due_to date to UTC before storing
        // if (postData.type === 'event') {
        //   postData['event.due_to'] = moment.utc(postData['event.due_to']).format();
        // }

        const post = await Post.create(postData);

        if (post._content_mentions.length !== 0) {

            // Create Notification for mentions on post content
            notifications.newPostMentions(post);

            // start the process to send an email to every user mentioned
            post._content_mentions.forEach((user, i) => {
                sendMail.userMentionedPost(post, user, i);
            });
        }

        // Send Email notification after post creation
        switch (post.type) {
            case 'task':
                await notifications.newTaskAssignment(post);
                await sendMail.taskAssigned(post);
                break;
            case 'event':
                await notifications.newEventAssignments(post);
                await sendMail.eventAssigned(post);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'New post created!',
            post
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return sendErr(res, err);
    }
};
```

**console.log(req.body) in the code above**

```
req.body { 'event._assigned_to': '5c34e8b57b82e019b09f569d',
  content: '<p>2:30PM</p>',
  type: 'event',
  _posted_by: '5c34e8b57b82e019b09f569d',
  _group: '5c34e8b57b82e019b09f569e',
  'event.due_to': '2019-01-09 02:30:00.000' }
```

**part of the angular front end that handles the time settings before sending the new post to the server**

```
// create date object for this event
    const date = new Date(this.model_date.year, this.model_date.month -1, this.model_date.day, this.model_time.hour, this.model_time.minute);

    const post = {
      content: this.post.content,
      type: this.post.type,
      _posted_by: this.user_data.user_id,
      _group: this.group_id,
      event: {
        due_date: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        due_time: moment(date).format('hh:mm:ss.SSS'),
        due_to: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS'),
        // problem: assignedUsers will always be empty
        _assigned_to: assignedUsers,
        _content_mentions: this.content_mentions
      },
      files: this.filesToUpload
    };
```

Comment: You have a commented line of code that uses moment.js; why is it commented? It's something I was going to suggest using. But it basically comes down to how javascript works with dates, and the timezone of the machine where the code runs.

Comment: The project leader wants to create an app where we assume people are in the same timezone, so he suggested that I removed saving the times in UTC and just use local times.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, especially if it's related to scheduling. In Javascript dates are by default always local dates, so it's hard to reason about transformations that happen while serializing and deserializing. Moment will format the date including the timezone, which Javascript's toString doesn't do, so using Moment (or using toISOString) removes some ambiguities. Generally as a best practice you should store UTC dates in your database (or structures that preserve the offset from UTC but for Javascript I'd just go with UTC)